# How to resample a time series depending on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to resample my data for 30 minutes if it is recorded in the **NIGHT** and 15 minutes in the **DAY**. Whether it is night or day, can be seen in *CYCLE_PART* column.

Here is the sample data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_TIME': pd.date_range('2022-11-01', '2022-11-06 23:00:00', freq='20min'),
                   'ID': [random.randrange(1, 20) for n in range(430)]})

df['VALUE1'] = [random.randrange(110, 140) for n in range(430)]
df['VALUE2'] = [random.randrange(50, 60) for n in range(430)]
df['VALUE3'] = [random.randrange(80, 100) for n in range(430)]
df['VALUE4'] = [random.randrange(30, 50) for n in range(430)]

df['MODEL'] = [random.randrange(1, 3) for n in range(430)]

df['SOLD'] = [random.randrange(0, 2) for n in range(430)]

df['INSPECTION'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.day

df['MODE'] = np.select([df['INSPECTION'] == 1, df['INSPECTION'].isin([2, 3])], ['A', 'B'], 'C')

df['TIME'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.time
# df['TIME'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['TIME'])
df['TIME'] = df['TIME'].astype('str')


# Create DAY Night columns only-------------------------------------------------------------------------
def cycle_day_period(dataframe: pd.DataFrame, midnight='00:00:00', start_of_morning='06:00:00',
                     start_of_afternoon='13:00:00',
                     start_of_evening='18:00:00', end_of_evening='23:00:00', start_of_night='24:00:00'):
    bins = [midnight, start_of_morning, start_of_afternoon, start_of_evening, end_of_evening, start_of_night]
    labels = ['Night', 'Morning', 'Morning', 'Night', 'Night']

    return pd.cut(
        pd.to_timedelta(dataframe),
        bins=list(map(pd.Timedelta, bins)),
        labels=labels, right=False, ordered=False
    )


df['CYCLE_PART'] = cycle_day_period(df['TIME'], '00:00:00', '06:00:00', '13:00:00', '18:00:00', '23:00:00', '24:00:00')
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
freq = {'Night': '30min', 'Morning': '15min'}
out = (df.groupby('CYCLE_PART')
         .apply(lambda g: g.resample(freq[g.name], on='DATE_TIME').mean())
         .reset_index()
       )
```

Output:

```
    CYCLE_PART           DATE_TIME    ID  VALUE1  VALUE2  VALUE3  VALUE4  MODEL  SOLD  INSPECTION
0      Morning 2022-11-01 06:00:00   4.0   122.0    50.0    80.0    48.0    1.0   0.0         1.0
1      Morning 2022-11-01 06:15:00   2.0   123.0    59.0    93.0    47.0    1.0   1.0         1.0
2      Morning 2022-11-01 06:30:00   3.0   125.0    59.0    90.0    40.0    1.0   1.0         1.0
3      Morning 2022-11-01 06:45:00   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN         NaN
4      Morning 2022-11-01 07:00:00  16.0   134.0    59.0    82.0    35.0    1.0   0.0         1.0
..         ...                 ...   ...     ...     ...     ...     ...    ...   ...         ...
809      Night 2022-11-06 21:00:00   9.0   118.5    55.0    88.0    39.0    2.0   0.5         6.0
810      Night 2022-11-06 21:30:00   4.0   129.0    53.0    98.0    34.0    1.0   0.0         6.0
811      Night 2022-11-06 22:00:00   7.5   120.5    52.5    87.0    39.5    2.0   0.5         6.0
812      Night 2022-11-06 22:30:00  15.0   122.0    54.0    84.0    30.0    1.0   0.0         6.0
813      Night 2022-11-06 23:00:00   9.0   117.0    59.0    82.0    36.0    1.0   0.0         6.0

[814 rows x 10 columns]
```

Comment: CYCLE_PART and DATE_TIME columns disappear when I print out the **out** variable. Is there any way to see those two columns? @mozway

Comment: Strange, which pandas version do you have?

Comment: I have version 1.5.1

Comment: I tried on 1.5.2 but I don't see why it wouldn't work on 1.5.1

Comment: I have upgraded my Pandas to 1.5.3 and I use PyCharm IDE. I still cannot see those 
CYCLE_PART,DATE_TIME, and even TIME columns..